# Why i am not getting expected output while passing char to a function in C

Tags: c, char, function-call

Here is the code I have written

```
#include<stdio.h>

main( )
{
    float a = 15.5 ;
    char ch = 'd' ;
    printit ( a, ch );
}
printit ( a, ch )
{
    printf ( "\n%f  %c ", a, ch ) ;
}
```

And the output is:

> 15.500000       ─

Here I am expecting the char `d` to be printed in place of `-`.

Comment: 1) Format your code properly. 2) You should get a warning already for a missing declaration (aka prototype) of `printit`. Also this is prehistoric C (aka K&R-C). **Never ever** use this. It is outdated since ca. 27 years. And the code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: **Never** write C code in this way .. besides the problem of undefined behavor, this code is really hard to understand.

Comment: you didn't have `printit` prototype/declaration before it's used. And mind your indentation

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You're using a dangerous (thankfully, now non-standard<sup>Ref</sup>) way of getting the variable types, that is, *type defaults to `int`*.

As your variables are missing datatype definitions, they default to `int`. So, inside `printtit()`, `a` and `ch` are of type `int`.

Now, by passing `a` as the argument for `%f`, you invoke UB already. The program (and it's output) can neither be trusted nor be justified in any way.

**Note : Enable compiler warnings and pay attention to them!**

---

Ref: Quoting from `C11` (available in `C99` also),

> Major changes in the second edition included:
>
> . . . .
>
> — remove implicit int

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has been solved, I wanted to add a correctly rewritten version of your code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printit (float, char); // function declaration

int main(void)
{
    float a = 15.5 ;
    char ch = 'd' ;
    printit (a, ch);
    return (0);
}
void printit (float a, char ch)
{
    printf("\n%f  %c ", a, ch) ;
}
```